# Is it grammatical idiomatic to say "pick us something", I guess so and I need a double check

Tags: word-usage, expressions

it sounds the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=131)

> the value of our function at this point is therefore clearly just f(x).
>
> we're going to use the same logic
>   as before, so we now need to `pick us` second point to draw our rise
>   over run triangle.

is it grammatical idiomatic to say "pick us something", I guess so, things like "pick us an apple".

but when I search "pick us an apple" on google, there are only 2 results which may indicates this is a rarely used expression, so I need a double check.

Comment: *Pick us an apple* is fine—although a lot more common would be *pick an apple **for** us.* However, your quoted text is full of errors and a terrible example.

Comment: The lecturer in the video is saying "pick a second point", while emphasiing "second". NB "Rise-over-run" normally hyphenated as an adjective. I'm not sure what errors the other commenter noticed: this is a well-spoken lecturer from a major university describing introductory calculus.  He speaks standard British English (though with "zee" for the letter), and I would have said was a good example if this is the subject matter you are learning English for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really learning English by following this course, so that's why I asked so much detail. What does `though with "zee" for the letter` mean? Does the lecturer add extra `zee` in his spoken?

Comment: (though with "zee" for the letter) means he pronounces the letter z as "zee" which is unusual for British English.  They typically pronounce z as "zed" in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

The lecturer in the video is saying "pick a second point", he does *not* say "pick us second point".

The auto-generated youtube subtitles are often mistaken.